# Use xmodmap returns me "bad keysym"

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, customization

I would remap my keyboard as following:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 77= w W {" 
xmodmap -e "keycode 78= x X }"

xmodmap -e "keycode 24= a A @"
xmodmap -e "keycode 49= ` & 2"
xmodmap -e "keycode 65= space space _"

xmodmap -e "keycode 111= Up Up Down"
xmodmap -e "keycode 113= Left Left Right"


xmodmap -e "keycode 51= * \" \' "

xmodmap -e "keycode 113= Left Left Right"
xmodmap -e "keycode 113= Left Left Right"
```

But xmodmap returns me:

> xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad keysym name 'XF86XK_{' in keysym list

I have seen on the web I should firstly remove the key but I m wondering if that could create some bug, so before trying a move I would ask the community some advice,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error you mentioned, use as `xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = w W braceleft"`

get the keysym from xev command.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x195, subw 0x0, time 470232, (535,249), root:(623,392),
    state 0x2001, keycode 34 (keysym 0x7b, braceleft), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 16
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7b) "{"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7b) "{"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x195, subw 0x0, time 470424, (535,249), root:(623,392),
    state 0x2001, keycode 34 (keysym 0x7b, braceleft), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 16
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7b) "{"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

If I understood correctly, your keycode 77 is <kbd>Num_Lock</kbd>

so, you want to make your <kbd>Num_Lock</kbd> key as `w` `W` and `braceleft`

to achieve this..

1. `xmodmap -e "remove Mod2 = Num_Lock"` this will remove the Modifier Num_Lock from the Num_Lock Key..

Note: Assign Num_Lock keysym to anyother keycode other wise you will loose Num_Lock. (this is not covered at this stage)

2. `xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = NoSymbol NoSymbol w W braceleft"`

you dont need to worry about removing the Modifier as above two changes will not persist after a logout or reboot.

Example for Swapping of Num_Lock and braceleft keysymbols

```
$ xmodmap -e "remove Mod2 = Num_Lock"
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 34 = bracketleft Num_Lock"
$ xmodmap -e "add Mod2 = Num_Lock"
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = braceleft"
$
```

Comment: thanks for answer, my keyboard is an azerty, keycode 77 is the `w` letter, I will review your answer asap :)

Comment: in that case no need to use `remove Mod2` `add Mod2` etc.. ignore them..